# 500 Interval server error in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I would like to ask what are the causes of this error? When i check the inspect elements to check it out, it said console.log(xhr.status); console.log(xhr.responseText); console.log(thrownError); are my errors. what is wrong in here?

My view

```
<h3> Product
  <a href="#new_product" data-toggle="modal" ><input type="hidden" class="btn btn-primary"><span class = "fa fa-plus-square-o "></a>

  <div class="modal fade" id="new_product" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Product</h4>
        </div>
        <form method="post"  id="form-submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- <form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" name = "select_design"action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Administrator/new_product"> -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- <div class="form-group">
               <label class="control-label ">Genre:</label>
                 <select name = "product_genre" class="select2_multiple " multiple="multiple" >
                   <option>Choose option</option>
                   <option value ="drama">Drama</option>
                   <option value ="action">Action</option>
                   <option value ="comedy">Comedy</option>
                   <option value ="horror">Horror</option>
                 </select>
             </div> -->

            <div class="form-group">

              <label>Product Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_name" name="product_name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo set_value('product_name'); ?>"> </div>

            <div class="form-group">             
              <label>Product Description</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_description" name="product_description" placeholder="Description" value="<?php echo set_value('product_description'); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">             
              <label>Stocks</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" value="<?php echo set_value('quantity'); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">             
              <label>Product Image</label>
              <input type="file" required class="form-control" id="userfile" name="userfile">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">             
              <label>Product Price</label>
              <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" id="product_price" name="product_price" placeholder="Price" value="<?php echo set_value('price'); ?>">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My js**

```
<script>

 $("#form-submit").on('submit',function(event){
      // $.LoadingOverlay("show");
      var form = new FormData(document.getElementById("form-submit"));
      $.ajax({
          url: base_url + "Administrator/new_product",
          type: "POST",
          data: form,
          processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
          contentType: false, // tell jQuery not to set contentType

          success: function(data) {
              var result = JSON.parse(data);
              //alert(data);
              if(result===1)
              {
                swal({
                      type: 'success',
                      html: 'New Product Added',
                      timer: 2000,
                      })
                 setTimeout(function() {
                 document.location.href= base_url + "Administrator/view_products";
                 }, 2000);

              }
              else
              {
                swal({
                  type: 'error',
                  html: result
                });
              }
              // $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
          },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       console.log(xhr.status);
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
       console.log(thrownError);
   }
      })
      event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

**My controller**

```
public function new_product()
{
    // $data['new_product'] = $this->AdministratorModel->getCourses();


    $config['upload_path'] = './products/';   
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048000';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;          

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">', '</div>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_name', ' Name', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_description', ' Name', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('quantity', 'stocks', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_price', 'price', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'image', 'callback_handle_upload');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
    { 

        echo json_encode(validation_errors());

    } 
    else 
    {

     $products = array(
        'product_name' => strip_tags($_POST['product_name']),
        'product_description' => strip_tags($_POST['product_description']),
        'product_category' => "Drama",
        'product_quantity' => strip_tags($_POST['quantity']),
        'product_image' => $this->input->post('userfile'),
        'upload_data' => $this->upload->data(),
        'product_price' => strip_tags($_POST['product_price'])
        );

    $this->AdministratorModel->addProduct($products);

    echo json_encode(1); 

    }
}
```

**My model**

```
public function addProduct($products)
{
     $products = array(
        'product_name' => strip_tags($_POST['product_name']),
        'product_description' => strip_tags($_POST['product_description']),
        'product_category' => strip_tags($_POST['product_genre']),
        'product_quantity' => strip_tags($_POST['quantity']),
        'product_image' => $this->input->post('userfile'),
        'product_image' => $this->upload->data('file_name'),
        'product_price' => strip_tags($_POST['product_price'])
        );
    $this->db->insert('products',$products);
}
```

Comment: 500 internal error occurs when your php syntax is wrong

Comment: 500 internal error occurs when your php syntax is SERIOUSLY wrong

Comment: Always check your server logs when you get 500 errors. It will give you an idea of what's wrong.

Comment: Which file is having error 500? The controller? We only have the url and cannot know which one it refers to

Comment: The file that having an error 500 is the view

Comment: Probably not the problem but in the view `<h3> Product` needs a closing `</h3>`.  Also, there seems to be an extra `</div>` at the end of the view.

Comment: check your response for the ajax call in the network tab in dev tools. you can see the error  in your script..